# Boxshadow to sides only

Tags: css

I need to have a boxshadow only showing on the sides. That is no shadow to be at the bottom of the div. My boxshadow css which gives shadows on side and bottom looks like:

```
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
```

Reading other posts on stackoverflow I've tried:

```
box-shadow: 5px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
```

But doesn't work. Any help on how to achieve would the effect would be much appreciated. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use pseudo elements to cover the top/bottom shadows.

```css
div {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  width: 100px; 
  height: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
div:before, div:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  content: '';
  background: white;
}
div:before {
  height: 2px; /* 3px - 1px */
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
div:after {
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  height: 4px; /* 3px + 1px */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative value for the `spread-radius` argument to multiple box shadows, one for the left and the other for the right. This works if the absolute value of the spread radius value is equal to or greater than the `blur-radius`.

```css
div {
  margin: 30px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 75px;
  box-shadow: -5px 0 3px -4px black, 5px 0 3px -4px black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```